# How to update multiple records at once in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to remove the below loop from rails code.

```
list=Student.find_by_sql("select study_id from students where id in (1,2,3,4,5)") 

list.each do |val|
  Subject.where(:sub_id=>val).update({:sub_code=> 'SO1'})
end
```

How can I rewrite these code without looping list and directly pass list in where condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the subjects and students table to query the subjects that need to be updated like below:

```
subjects = Subject.joins('INNER JOIN students ON subjects.sub_id = students.study_id').where('students.id IN (?)', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

subjects.update(sub_code: 'SO1')
```

Comment: I have done id hard-coded but it is not hard-coded .The Id is coming in for of objects ex.  Object1=[{"id": 1},{"id": 2}, {"id": 3},]

Comment: @AsSh Well, I used the data exactly in the format you shared in your question. If you are getting data like  `obj = [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}, {"id": 3},..]` instead, you can do `obj.pluck('id')` to get the array of student ids and use it in the query. there is no need of downvoting the answer just because you posted half question and expect us to answer based on the other half as well.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the primary keys, that are not following Rails conventions, and the association between `Subject` and `Student` correctly configured, then you would be able to write:

```
student_ids = (1..5) # or just an array of ids
Subject.joins(:students)
       .where(students: { id: student_ids })
       .update_all(sub_code: 'S01')
```

It is worth noting that [`update_all`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord/ActiveRecord%2FRelation:update_all) creates only one query, filtering and updating the records directly via SQL. But because `update_all` just generates one SQL query, it by-passed and skips validations and callbacks. Which might be okay for a simple, single attribute update when there are no validations or callbacks depending on that attribute.

But when you want to ensure that validations and callbacks are run, you cannot avoid loading the records into memory and using [`update`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord/ActiveRecord/Persistence#update-instance_method) or even [`update!`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord/ActiveRecord/Persistence#update!-instance_method) like this:

```
Subject.joins(:students)
       .where(students: { id: student_ids })
       .each do |subject|
  subject.update_all(sub_code: 'S01')
end
```

This version is still better than the version from the question, because it loads all records into memory with just one query and only updates them individually. Whereas the version from the question loads each record into memory with individual queries.

Comment: This is a good answer but there should be mentioned that while `update_all` makes just one query for all the records, it does not run callbacks. If OP needs callbacks they can call `update` instead of `update_all` but this would still run a loop in the background.

Comment: @JanVítek Great point. I updated my answer to address this topic.